# i'm trying to create an anti vowel prog in my own original way but for some reason one vowel makes the prog fail

Tags: python

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    empL = [] #just an empty list
    index = 0 #just an index counter
    empS = "" #just an empty String
    for i in text: 
        empL.append(i) # in this loop ill be adding the str passed in by "text" char by char to the empty list 
    else:   # since this its a for/else loop this is also going to run
        for char in empL: # iterates to each element in the list  
            if char in "aeiouAEIOU": **# if the element thats being iterated at the moment is cotained in this string**
                empL.remove(char) #remove it
        else: #yes this is going to run because it's another for/else
            sizeEmpL = len(empL) # just the size of empty list
            while sizeEmpL != 0 :
                empS = empS + empL[index]
                print(empS)
                index += 1
                sizeEmpL -= 1
            print(empL)
            print(empS)
```

so basically I'm supposed to pass a string as a parameter the prog is supposed to put char by char in an empty list and the check each char compared to the string "aeiouAEIOU" and if the char compared contains any of the "aeiouAEIOU" then it's supposed to remove it.
then I add the elements to an empty string and print out the vowelless String

Comment: So you're just supposed to remove vowels from a string?

Comment: Describe the input the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: `''.join([c for c in text if c.lower() not in 'aeiou'])`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Nice -- that's easy for an experienced Python user to understand. This looks to be homework, however.

Comment: It's not homework I'm doing the python section in code academy! but the solution I see everywhere it's similar to the one you provided and I was trying to make it in my own way. It seems what I came up with isn't possible thanks for the help guys! @PatrickHaugh

Comment: input is ("words between words") and output is "wrds btwen wrds" so the e was ignored by the code somewhere @MarkTolonen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing elements from a list while you're iterating over it doesn't work as you expect. Don't modify the list while you are iterating over it.   Here is the problem code:

```
for char in empL:
    if char in "aeiouAEIOU":
        empL.remove(char)
```

Shortening the list while iterating over it has the effect of skipping other characters in the list.

Comment: thanks it seems it ignored that detail of iterating @MarkTolonen

Comment: @franny  Instead of iterating over a list and removing characters, iterate over the original text and add non-vowels to a new string. Then you aren't modifying the iterator.  Also, give thanks on SO by upvoting and accepting an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'ofiiajpfeiajpfeiaef   ijgapijfpij'

''.join([x for x in string if x not in ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']])
```

output:

```
'fjpfjpff   jgpjfpj'
```

you can make a function of it:

```
def no_vowels(input_string):  
    return (''.join([x for x in input_string if x not in ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']]))
```

hope that helps